# Destruct react props using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to desctruct react props that I pass to component with Typescript.
These are my props:

```
export type IssueListHomeProps = {
    projects: ProjectDtoImpl[];
    issues: IssueDtoImpl[];
    timeEntries: TimeEntryDtoImpl[];
    handleRefresh: () => void;
    changeMode: (m: string) => void;
    selectTimeEntry: (entry: TimeEntryDtoImpl) => void;
    pullToRefresh: boolean;
    dates: string[];
} & RouteComponentProps;
```

That's how I'm trying to do this:

```
const {projects: ProjectDtoImpl[], issues: IssueDtoImpl[],timeEntries: TimeEntryDtoImpl[],pullToRefresh: boolean, dates: string[]} = this.props
```

But I get errors like these:

```
1.Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
2.Expression expected
```

I don't know where to do this: in component or outside, or may be in the constructor?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What Element is the error talking about? As for the second error, you probably have missing colon, comma, or semicolon somewhere. Have you tried destructuring your props without indicating their type? They should implicitly have a type by this point. `const {projects, issues, timeEntries, pullToRefresh, dates} = this.props`

Answer (score 2):

Well, It is incorrect to use types in destruction; The correct way is to make it like this:

```
render() {
    const {
      projects,
      issues,
      timeEntries,
      pullToRefresh,
      dates
    }: IssueListHomeProps = this.props;
```